# Materialize a Set of String From flatten()

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

It has been a struggle to attempt to return a set(string) from a call to flatten() against a complex object.

My Attempt:

**In dev.tfvars**

```
    source_endpoints = [
        {
            name = "DBSERVER01",
            ip_address = "xxx.xx.x.xxx"
            port = "1433",
            client_databases = [
                "DB01",
                "DB02"             
            ]
        },
        {
            name = "DBSERVER02",
            ip_address = "xxx.xx.x.xxx"
            port = "1433",
            client_databases = [
                "DB03",
                "DB04"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**In locals.tf**

```
locals {
  database_names = flatten([
    for x, source_endpoint in var.source_endpoints : [
       for y, client_database in source_endpoint.client_databases : [      
                client_database 
      ]
    ]   
  ])
}
```

**Applied To Resource:**

```
    resource "aws_s3_object" "bronze-cdc" {
      for_each     = local.database_names
      bucket       = module.s3_bronze.bucket.id
      key          = "${each.value}/cdc-files/"
      content_type = "application/x-directory"
    }
```

**Terraform Plan Error :**

```
> Error: Invalid for_each argument
> 
>   on s3-folders.tf line 19, in resource "aws_s3_object" "silver-dbo": 
> 19:   for_each     = local.database_names
>     ├────────────────
>     │ local.database_names is tuple with 4 elements
> 
> The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each"
> argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a
> value of type tuple.
```

**Desired Result of local.database_names:**

```
["DB01","DB02","DB03","DB04"]
```

I know there must be a way to project the result to a set(string), I just have not stumbled across any example. Any Advice is welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried using `toset(local.database_names)`?

Comment: No, but that seems like a logical way forward. I will attempt that now.

Comment: @MarkoE - Worked perfectly. If you post as answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error output:

```
"for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.
```

The list type of the local variable can be converted to a set (which works with `for_each`) by using the built-in `toset` [1] function:

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "bronze-cdc" {
  for_each     = toset(local.database_names)
  bucket       = module.s3_bronze.bucket.id
  key          = "${each.value}/cdc-files/"
  content_type = "application/x-directory"
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/toset